# ${P(|X|\geq \lambda)\leq f(\lambda)}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have to prove a bound of the form $$P(|X|\geq \lambda)\leq f(\lambda)\quad (1),$$where $f$ denotes some upper bound function and $X$ is a *complex* random variable.

My question is: I know a bound on the real and imaginary part of the random variable, i.e. $$P(|\Re X|\geq \lambda)\leq f_1(\lambda)\\P(|\Im X|\geq \lambda)\leq f_2(\lambda),$$how can I use these bounds to prove the bound $(1)$, i.e. to construct $f$  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$
\max\{|\Re X|,|\Im X|\}\leq|X|=\sqrt{|\Re X|^2+|\Im X|^2}\leq |\Re X|+|\Im X|.
$$
Then
$$
|X|\geq\lambda\implies |\Re X|\geq\lambda/2\quad\text{or}\quad|\Im X|\geq\lambda/2
$$
so that
$$
\Pr(|X|\geq\lambda)\leq\Pr[(|\Re X|\geq\lambda/2)\cup(|\Im X|\geq\lambda/2)]\leq f_1(\lambda/2)+f_2(\lambda/2).
$$
Thus, $f(\lambda)\equiv f_1(\lambda/2)+f_2(\lambda/2)$ works.